# failed to compute cache key: "/dist" not found: not found

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-build

My Docker File -

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="production"
EXPOSE  5000
WORKDIR /app
COPY  ./dist . 
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "JustLogin.API.dll"]
```

The Image builds successfully via command prompt but when trying to run in it via visual studio it throws error and by docker desktop it doesn't shows any error but site still doesn't run

Comment: Can you check if the directory where you run `docker build` actually has the `dist` directory in it? It could be that the root directory where VS is building from is different.

Comment: yes it is as the same location

Comment: Can you put here what's the command that VS uses to build the image?

Comment: If possible, can you show your filesystem showing `dist` and the Dockerfile? You can blur other information if necessary.

Comment: Is there a reason you are building on your local machine and copying into the container? I imagine the arch is going to be fairly different. Worth adhering to the MS default where you can https://docs.docker.com/samples/dotnetcore/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the dist folder location was inside child folder.But project was building by default for root path

Answer (score 0):

You can check `.dockerignore` file. If there is a `**/dist` keyword in `.dockerignore` file, you should delete it.